# color of first conour was changed after plotting second contour

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, contour

My first contour is:

```
figure
x = -2:0.2:2;
y = -2:0.2:3;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = X.*exp(-X.^2-Y.^2);
contour(X,Y,Z,'LineWidth', 2)
```

[image]

then i plot the second contour:

```
hold on
x = -2:0.2:2;
y = -2:0.2:3;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = exp(-X.^2-Y.^2);
contour(X,Y,Z,'LineWidth', 2)
```

[image]

as be seen, color of first contour was changed.
How can I do to maintain first contour colors?

Comment: the colors are determined by mapping the range of `Z` to the colormap. the first plot `max(Z)` is smaller than `max(Z)` of the second plot and therefore, the mapping changed. If you plot the second before the first, it will maintain the same colors.

Comment: @Shai Thank you for your reply, but your solution doesn't resolve my problem because mentioned codes are a little example and in my main code, I don't know which contour must be the first. I want to maintain color of first contour under any conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colors of the contours are changing because Matlab *automatically* changes the color mapping according to the values of `Z`. In order to fix the mapping, you can use [`caxis manual`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html) to override the default `caxis auto`.